# How to simulate AUV in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm looking at using Gazebo for simulating AUV in a pool for the RoboSub Competition. I was wondering if anyone knows if that is something that can be done and also if any world files exist for the competition arena.

Thank you.

Gunnlaugur

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8055/how-to-simulate-auv-in-gazebo?/) by [Gunnlaugur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1117/gunnlaugur/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a plugin called Freefloating gazebo ( https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo ).
The model is very simple but depending on accuracy level your project needs it can be useful. Also, you can change the code and improve the model if you want to.

---

Originally posted by [Eduardo Albuquerque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/948/eduardo-albuquerque/) with karma: 89 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1